# getContract from forked testnet

Tags: solidity, erc-20, hardhat, interfaces, test

when I run hardhat on forked testnet and try to run test script that includes

```
dai = await ethers.getContractAt("IERC20", DAI)
```

I get this error:

```
NomicLabsHardhatPluginError: 0x6B175474E89094C44Da98b954EedeAC495271d0F is not a contract account.
```

I tried different addresses but nothing seems to work.

this is my hardhat config.js

I use quicknode as url

```
  networks: {
        hardhat: {
            hardfork: "merge",
            // If you want to do some forking set `enabled` to true
            forking: {
                url: `${process.env.QUICKNODE_API_KEY_MUMBAI}`,
                //blockNumber: FORKING_BLOCK_NUMBER,
                enabled: true,
            },
            chainId: 31337,
        },
        localhost: {
            chainId: 31337,
        },
```

And ran it as follows: npx hardhat node --network hardhat and it works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, it seems DAI is not implemented on the testnet polygon mumbai  so I had to change the API key to mainnet polygon and change the address of the DAI